# Binary Heap class constructor

Tags: java, arrays

Can anyone explain the BinaryHeap constructor? (see below the java codes)
I don't understand the following lines:

- array = (AnyType[]) new Comparable[ ( currentSize + 2 ) * 11 / 10 ];
- for( AnyType item : items)
  array[ i++ ] = item;

  ```
  public BinaryHeap( AnyType [ ] items ) {
      currentSize = items.length;
      array = (AnyType[]) new Comparable[ ( currentSize + 2 ) * 11 / 10 ];

      int i = 1;
      for( AnyType item : items )
          array[ i++ ] = item;
      buildHeap( );
  }
  ```

  ...

  }

Comment: I do understand the Generics, but that line of codes constructing the array is pretty new to me. Also, I don't understand that for-each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `BinaryHeap` class is defined as `BinaryHeap<AnyClass extends Comparable<AnyClass>>` or something similar. Thus, your problem is about understanding [generics in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). If you already know this, then is no rocket science: it creates an array of `Comparable` with a bigger size than the `items` array parameter by applying a formula. Then, it applies a cast to `AnyClass[]` to the generated array.

Note: example of creating an array of generics:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    private T[] array;
    private int size = 10;
    public Foo() {
        //line below commented since it generates "generic array creation" compile error
        //array = new T[size];
        //instead, this works without problems
        array = (T[]) new Object[size];
    }
}
```

In this case,since `AnyType` already extends `Comparable<? super AnyType>` (based on comments) then it would be safe to create an array of `Comparable` and then casting it to `AnyType[]`.

The `for` loop shown here is the [enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with). Since this `for` loop doesn't handle an index value (as in the common `for(int i = 0; ...)`) the programmer declare and initialize the index `i` before using this `for` and then using it inside, assuring the value of `i` raises on each loop by using `i++`.

Comment: the class is -- public class BinaryHeap<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>> { ... }

Comment: Is it common to build the array with "new Comparable[]" for an object that is comparable?

Comment: @JavaOwl this is done since you can't create an array of generics. Usually, you will see something like `T[] array = (T[])new Object[size];`. In this case, since `AnyType` already extends `Comparable<? super AnyType>` it will compile.

Comment: so if I construct an array for a <type extends Comparable>, I need to put "new Comparable[size]". Is that right?

Comment: @JavaOwl yes, and then apply a type cast to `type[]` as shown in the code above.

Comment: @JavaOwl you can create an array of classes, abstract classes and interfaces with no problems. Note that in the case of abstract classes and interfaces, the array will contain concrete objects that extends (or implements) the abstract class (or the interface), thus giving no problems when using the object instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.    array = (AnyType[]) new Comparable[ ( currentSize + 2 ) * 11 / 10 ];
```

A new `Comparable[]` is created with size `( currentSize + 2 ) * 11 / 10`.  It is then cast to type `(AntType[])` and assigned to the variable `array`.

```
2. for( AnyType item : items) array[ i++ ] = item;
```

The `for( AnyType item : items)` is just a shorthand for `for`, specifically a [for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).  It iterates over `items`, assigning each element to the variable `item` of type `AnyType`.  It then assigns that element to the `array` at index `i++` (while incrementing `i`).

Comment: Is it common to build the array with "new Comparable[]" for an object that is comparable?

Comment: so if I construct an array for a <type extends Comparable>, I need to put "new Comparable[size]". Is that right?